# What is the meaning of “les suivantes” in this context?

Tags: sens, histoire, société

This is an excerpt from the Russian poet Alexander Pushkin's short story "[**The Queen of Spades**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Queen_of_Spades_(story))":

> *—Il paraît que monsieur est décidément pour **les suivantes**?
>
>   —Que voulez-vous, madame? Elles sont plus fraîches.*
>
> ["It appears, monsieur, that you decidedly favour the lady's maids."
>   "Of course, madame; they're fresher."]
>
> Society Talk

As you can see, *les suivantes* has been translated as *the lady's maids*. I looked in a couple of online English-French dictionaries and none of them had that meaning. All of them said that *les suivantes* means *the following* or *the next*. Is the way they have it in the book, nevertheless, an accurate translation of this phrase or am I just missing something? Could you please back your answer up with some supporting evidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Définition du [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suivante)

> III. − Subst. Personne qui en accompagne une autre pour l'assister, la servir. Il est venu [à l'Assemblée], sans aucun doute avec des suivants (...) mais il doit s'avancer seul et les laisser à distance (Delacroix, Journal, 1854, p. 284).
>   − En partic., au fém. Dame de compagnie ou femme de chambre. La fidèle suivante. Cachant sa tête contre la poitrine de la suivante favorite (...), elle murmura dans un sanglot (...): « Oh! ma pauvre Nofré, je suis bien triste (...) » (Gautier, Rom. momie, 1858, p. 201).Deux des belles suivantes d'Antinéa, Aguida et Sydya, étaient au nombre des convives (Benoit, Atlant., 1919, p. 197).
>   ♦ P. métaph. Qu'a donc fait Philippe [Louis-Philippe] pour le pays?... Il a passé son temps (...) à dégrader la patrie en la faisant la suivante de l'Angleterre, en la livrant en otage (Chateaubr., Mém., t. 4, 1848, p. 520).Considérer la philosophie (...) comme la suivante et, tout au plus, comme la dame de compagnie de la religion (Sainte-Beuve, Nouv. lundis, t. 4, 1863, p. 269).

---

Ce pourrait être traduit par *« lady-in-waiting. »*